# Stacking squares/boxes

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help on a somewhat simple problem. I'm at the end of an assignment, where we are to make different art figures. I've made a "squares within a square" box and need to generate 4 rows and 4 columns of that box.

[image]

I think the best solution is a few for loops more, but can't quite make it work.

My code:

```
class StandardPanel extends JPanel{     

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){  

       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

       double alpha = Math.toRadians(5);
       double factor = 1 / (Math.sin(alpha) + Math.cos(alpha));
       double size = 200;

       g2d.translate(size, size);

       for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {

           int intSize = (int) Math.round(size);

           g2d.setColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.white);
           g2d.fillRect(-intSize / 2, -intSize / 2, intSize, intSize);
           g2d.setColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.black : Color.black);
           g2d.drawRect(-intSize / 2, -intSize / 2, intSize, intSize);

           size = size * factor;
           g2d.rotate(alpha);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What picture/How does it not quite work?

Comment: Since im new on this site, I can't post a picture of it yet. But my square looks simular to this:
http://www.computing.northampton.ac.uk/~gary/csy3019/images/ShapeSquareSwirl.jpg

Now i just need to generate up to 16 of it and make in to one big square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the drawing code in a double nested for-loop to create multiple of an object in a grid. Also, you need to re-translate the g2d object so it actually changes position relative to where it is in the grid:

```
for ( int row = 0; row < 4; row++ ) // 4 rows
{
  for ( int col = 0; col < 4; col++ ) // 4 columns
  {
    g2d.translate(row*size, col*size); // change the location of the object

     for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)  // draw it
     {
       int intSize = (int) Math.round(size);

       g2d.setColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.white);
       g2d.fillRect(-intSize / 2, -intSize / 2, intSize, intSize);
       g2d.setColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.black : Color.black);
       g2d.drawRect(-intSize / 2, -intSize / 2, intSize, intSize);

       size = size * factor;
       g2d.rotate(alpha);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the code I posted? The double nested for-loop is the first two loops before the loop you originally had in your code